# Is there a USB B to Ethernet Adapter for an External 3.5 Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, ethernet, nas

I have a 3.5" 4TB HHD in a cheap NexStar enclosure connected to my GS63VR laptop via usb 3.0 and it's 90% full. The data is/was in the process of being backed up to back blaze but it will take months, already on month 2. I just moved to France were voltage is now 240. I had the TV connected to the HDMI port. I touched the laptop one day and saw a spark more than once, it was stronger than your average static spark. I've since ruled out everything but the HDMI cable, I disconnected that and no more shocks. However, I think the shocks screwed up my USB ports. I've tried replacing the HD enclosure and power supplies. The laptop seems to connect to it when I turn it on most of the time but it disappears from This PC shortly after and doesn't come back, but the laptop still sees a USB unknown device connected. It's possible the HD was affected but my instinct says it is the ports... so I want to know if I can put this singular HD on the network like a NAS but without wiping the data obviously. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an XY problem.
For starters I would first check to see if the USB ports of your laptop aren't fried. Any other USB device, like a USB stick, printer, mouse, keyboard will do for that.

If you are sure the laptop is fine you just need a USB to SATA converter, or an empty enclosure, both which can be had for as little as 30 euro.
You just use that to hook up the disk itself to the laptop.

If the laptop is fried you've got a bigger problem. It will probably degrade further over time, become unreliable and will have to be replaced eventually.

As you already said so yourself a NAS is usually the solution to put a disk "on the network" but EVERY NAS I have ever seen wipes the disk(s) first.
The only way around that is to find a cheap NAS with USB port. Put another disk in that NAS to get the NAS working/configured. Then attach your 4TB disk to that USB port as additional device. That won't wipe it and you can share the disk via the NAS.

There is an alternative though. Many SOHO routers have a USB port to which you can attach a USB stick or USB disk and share it where the router acts as the NAS. If your router has that functionality that is your cheap way out.
In fact. Buying a router just for that will actually be CHEAPER than buying a NAS+extra disk.

(P.S. Some fancy printer/scanner multifunctional machines may have this functionality too.)

Bear in mind that your laptops USB AND the USB of the disk-enclosure may BOTH be fried. Actually it wouldn't surprise me at all if that is the case. In that case you still need a new enclosure or USB-SATA converter to hook up the disk to the NAS or router.

Comment: That is fair. USB works for mouse but that tended to fail at the same time. Also the HDD stayed connected overnight to my work computer. Discovery: surprisingly the most likely cause is RJ45. I turned my laptop 90 deg yesterday which took some strain of the RJ45 cable lying on top of the usb cable. Doubt it was interference, but a tiny bit of strain on the RJ45 port... Last night I turned the laptop 45deg from original position, it stayed connected many hours but disconnected. Now it's the full 90 again, will see what happens... in orig position it disconnects after sec/min.

Comment: Bought a DS420j and 4 4TB WD red drives with SHR setup, transferring everything now with teracopy, will validate with something else after but teracopy is validating too. As long as it stays okay for the transfer long enough to get it to NAS should be okay. Backblaze for secondary. Crazy the RJ45 port straight seems to be the issue... But who knows really... Fyi, tried new usb enclosure and cables and power supplies with the old drive and a different one, issue was still present, so unlikely anything external. I think power issues caused a short and RJ45 strain creates the intermittent.

Comment: @gunslinger RJ45 ports (and video-ports) are prone to this. The mechanical strain of a heavy/stiff cable hanging from it (possibly under tension tool) tends to gradually weaken the connection between socket to motherboard. This is especially a problem for laptops as there is less room for a beefier/stronger connector, people put more strain on the cables as they move the laptop around and on a laptop the connectors are plugged in/out a lot more. It all adds up. The connector may have been flaky for a while, but you only notice it now cause you are paying extra attention.

Comment: I am slowly moving my data off this drive into the nas, will take all week assuming it survives, I think it disconnected like 50 times today. Got a drive coming from backblaze w/ 1.6TB of my data, should be the partial backup before all this happened. 4 months of backblaze trying to backup this drive probably played a role in this failure. I have just now come to the POTENTIAL conclusion it is the hdd, and it's temperature related, tiny bit above a certain temp it cuts out maybe. Testing. Opened enclosure, extra heat syncs. Thank God for teracopy, if it's working as shld, Will keep posted.

Comment: Well, I still no idea what's wrong ... Best guess, multiple point failure... Drive is dieing, usb is dieing, enclosure and power is fine but probably played a role... 5y of 120V, then 1 week of 240V and poop. It seemed random when it would disconnect. I've transfered 500gb with out an insident... But just now I was at 300gb and touch the key pad, disconnected. Everything else seems fine... usb works with just a mouse dongle without issue, drive works in another computer, at least 18h anyway, I think they just hate each other after uploading 1.5TB to the cloud. Nas should be done in 2 days.